# Adding icons to field labels

Tags: 7, entities

How do I add icons next to field names, like adding a [phone](http://www.carloancentre.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Contact-Methods-Phone-icon.png) icon in front of the mobile phone field?

i tried the patches shown in https://www.drupal.org/node/2050257, but they do not seem to work.

I have seen this on some websites, so I guess it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the label using the [template_preprocess_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) hook.

For instance, if your field was named "phone" and the content type was "business", you could add this to your template.php:

```
template_preprocess_field (&$variables) {
  $content_type = $variables['element']['#bundle'];
  $field_name = $variables['element']['#field_name'];

  if ($content_type == 'business' && $field_name == 'phone') {
    $variables['label'] = '<img src="http://www.carloancentre.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Contact-Methods-Phone-icon.png" height="16" width="16"/>' . $variables['label'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve using css

```
#field-name {
  background-image: url('image/path/ico_phone.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create field template file and apply css.

see this links : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7

Comment: Creating a template file is not a need.

Answer (score 0):

you need create #field_prefix , add HTML image or element icon font into `#field_prefix` ! Read [Document about form API Drupal](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/)

Answer (score -1):

I will advice to fix this issue by using the [CSS injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector) module to add the necessary CSS styles to show an icon before the field label.

> Allows administrators to inject CSS into the page output based on configurable rules. It's useful for adding simple CSS tweaks without modifying a site's official theme. The CSS is added using Drupal's standard `drupal_add_css()` function and respects page caching, etc. The 2.x brach leverages CTools so CSS can be included with Feature changes (ie. CSS that improves the look of a View can be packaged with the View).

Comment: Will try this and get back to you. Although a gui would be ideal

Comment: It would be useful to show the OP the CSS selector necessary to select a field label.