# How to put icon in field label?

Tags: entities

Is it possible to add an icon in front of a field name?

I have a field name called Tel and would like to put a phone icon in front of it?

I've searched for a while and can't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: Use css, you can check here same question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150802/adding-icons-to-field-labels

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I am very new to Drupal so forgive me if Im asking obvious questions.. Would I just put this into my css so? #field-name {
  background-image: url('image/path/ico_phone.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

Comment: Or do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Use Font Awesome classes to add the icons for the field label.

Comment: I have downloaded Font Awesome, however, it only lets me add icons in the body of the text and not in the label name of my content type. Is there a certain way I can add it to the label using Font Awesome?

Comment: let me know you want to chaneg the label of field for admin panel and front end both.

Comment: Yes I want to change it for both.

Comment: @Karuna details please